# IE7 dropdown menu moves to top, and jquery not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

The site in question is: http://shabalala.codedprojects.co.za/

You'll see the site has a dropdown menu at the top, which works fine except in IE7, it doesn't sit below the top nav but instead goes to the top of the page. Why is this?

On the home page as well, there are two sections at the bottom, Latest News and Specials, which don't display at all on IE7. Is there something I can do to fix this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove top:100% for IE 7 in  "nav ul ul" class..